# How do I convert multiple categorical variables into binary based on their value (Python)?

Tags: python, classification, data-analysis, data-conversion

I am trying to do a classification project and I need to make the target variable into binary. The target variable is "quality" and all the values are from 0-10. I am trying to make values less than 6.5 = 'poor', and values greater than 6.5 = 'good'. I'll have 0 mean 'poor' and 1 mean 'good'. I was going to use .replace(), but they are float values with decimal numbers and there's no way I could get all of them with just .replace(). and how would I get it back in the dataset df.

Any type of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I had tried to use .replace(), which otherwise would have worked if the values were whole numbers. I am stuck.

Comment: You say 'binary', but it sounds more like you're after a boolean, or an integer? Also, the comparison you're after seems to be a numerical one, but you're trying to solve this using string replacement? What does your data look like? Please share the code you tried so far, so people know what you need explained and what is clear already.

Comment: If `quality` is a `list`, then you can do it with a comprehension: `quality = [0 if q < 6.5 else 1 for q in quality]`. Note this assumes values >= 6.5 are good. Otherwise, I'll need to see what `quality` looks like to help.

Comment: From the information that you have provided it is still a little vague as to what you are expecting as the output, but I think the solution to your dilemma is either `LabelEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder`.

Answer (score 0):

Code for NumPy. Pass your list of data to NumPy array, then with the comparison operator you create an array of booleans corresponding to the data, but you can cast it to `float32` so `True` becomes `1.0` and `False` becomes `0.0`. Hope that helps

```
import numpy as np

raw_y = np.array([1.0 , 2.0, 5.2, 9.2, 4.8])

print(raw_y)

y = np.array(raw_y > 6.5, dtype=np.float32)

print(y)
```

Output

```
[1.  2.  5.2 9.2 4.8]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a numpy array, Andrew's solution works.
In case you are working with a pandas dataframe or CSV you can replace by reassigning, here is a snippet

```
import pandas as pd    
ddf=pd.DataFrame()    
ddf['class']=[7,6,5,4,8,7,9,3,2,1]    
ddf.loc[((ddf['class']<=6.5)),'new_class']=0  
ddf.loc[((ddf['class']>6.5)) ,'new_class']=1
```

Comment: Simpler: `ddf['new_class'] = ddf['class'].gt(6.5).astype('int')`